# What reasons are there for views not rendering a link?

Tags: views

The link passes the nid and date to another view. List of classes presenting a link to a list of bookings.

In the following example John's class has a link but Jake's class does not.

The 'Add booking' and 'Claim' links work for all classes and pass the url as nid/time where time is in seconds rather than formatted to be passed to views. 
[image]

The date field is setup with the date formatted as follows

[image]

The link is created through rewriting

[image]

More things that don't work.

- Turn off Style settings > "add default classes"
- Just rewrite the text instead of "Output this field as a link". I get the half closed span. This is true if I rewrite the source field.

  2017-09-26AEST14:35">View Bookings
- Creating a plain text field and rewriting there. Same result as for rewriting inline.

I can see why taking the default classes away might work, as it might stop the date formatter wrapping the text. 
The link formatter looks like it is removing the span, so any other rewriting doesn't work.

Comment: Try [unchecking add default classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKciO.jpg) for `nid` and `field_when_2` fields configuration.

Comment: I tried it. Didn't do anything. If I view source on where the link should be there is no link rendered at all.

Comment: Change the text to `<a href="studio-manage.../[nid]/[field_when_2]">View bookings [nid]/[field_when_2]</a>` and disable **Output this field as a link**.  This may give you some insight into what is going on.

Comment: I tried using rewrite a number of ways. Couldn't get rid of a 'span'. It is calling a custom entity, so I've worked around the issue by defining the field as filter as 'numeric' rather than date and just passing the raw database value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you set up a source field:

- Create a source field with the date formatting.
- Rewrite the output of the field with just the tag. [date_when_2] in my case.
- Select "Strip HTML tags".

Then create a custom text field that rewrites the output as the link.